# How to access child component's formik values in parent component?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form in a child component. After it is been submitted, I need to access one of the form field value in parent component. I am not at all able to figure it out. I am not able to use `useFormik` as I have `<Formik />` component instead. I referred a lot but I am not able to figure this out

```
Parent component:

    import ChildForm from "./ChildForm";
    import "./styles.css";
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
             <ChildForm />
             Email Address: {/* firstName; child form's firstName value  */}
        </div> );
     }

Child component:

    const ChildComponent = () => {
      return (
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
          }}
          onSubmit={async (values) => {
            await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          }}
        >
          <Form>
            <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
            <Field id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" />

            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <Field id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe" />

            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <Field
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="jane@acme.com"
              type="email"
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </Form>
        </Formik>
      );
    };

A quick CodeSandBox to quick preview: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-nightingale-956xxv?file=/src/App.js:0-271
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, just pass function to from parent to child and accept form values as parameters

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-pascal-db2rbu?file=/src/App.js